# Scaling up loss/gradients to speed up convergence after error decrease has dropped to a slow but steady rate?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Has anyone looked at scaling up the gradients to speed up convergence ?

For example, when the error is dropping at a very slow but steady rate, change this

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
```

to this

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(2.0*loss)
```

Comment: There are a lot of variations on this: adapting the learning rate for each parameter (RMSProp, Adam), cyclic learning rates, random learning rates...

Comment: What class is `tf`?